# What is the correct option to use Grunt locally and on the production server, --save or --save-dev?

Tags: gruntjs

The [install page](http://gruntjs.com/installing-grunt) on the Grunt website gives the following suggestion

> Grunt and Grunt plugins should be defined as devDependencies in your
>   project's package.json. This will allow you to install all of your
>   project's dependencies with a single command: `npm install`.

I want to use grunt to run some tasks that are specific to local development, e.g.

- **development**: concatenate javascript, but dont minify
- **production**: concatenate *and* minify javascript

If I install Grunt as a dev dependency, does this mean when I run NPM install on the production server - grunt will not be installed into node modules?

What is the correct option to be able to use Grunt both locally **and** on the production server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you install Grunt as a dev dependency, it will still be installed when you run `npm install`.

The scenario where dev dependencies *are not* installed is when you run `npm install <package>` because the consensus is you are an end user looking to use (not build/test) the package. However, you can still include the dev dependencies by adding the `--dev` flag.

Comment: oh, so NPM basically assumes my project is being developed for the purpose of being added to the NPM repository, and when I add grunt to my project  with `npm install grunt --save-dev`  -  if/when an "end user" came to install my package via NPM repo (which basically wont happen as this is just a website project) NPM  says *"Oh Grunt was only needed while this guy was developing his package"* - and the "end user" will only  be given to the contents of my project - without grunt?

Comment: @user4668401 exactly :)

Answer (score 0):

You should install grunt with `--save-dev`. What it does is add a line to your project's `package.json`. Similar to when you install *any* other node module with `--save-dev`. Then, if you run `npm install` on any machine with the same `package.json`, all those modules will be downloaded and installed locally, and usable by your project.

As for running different tasks in production and development, I assume you know how to configure grunt to do that.